# How to open bathroom light cover to replace bulb?

Tags: cover, light

I cannot open the cover. I tried to twist it anti clock-wise, or clock-wise, or pull down. No success. Can anyone help? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are there any set screws above the bowl? They'd be almost flush with the ceiling, and positioned horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

Answered by OP in [comments](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/103048/how-to-open-bathroom-light-cover-to-replace-bulb#comment156427_103070):

> I did it! There is something like a little groove at the side - at the connection between black and white parts - wherein I slotted a screwdriver, twisted it, and the light cover pulled off. Eureka! – *Lukman Dec 17 '16 at 12:16*

Answer (score 0):

There is likely 3 screws evenly spaced around the metal base, that are holding the glass cover in.  Back them out and the cover will fall out.  Be careful with the last one to support the glass.

Comment: Unfortunately no such screws found on the cover.

Comment: Hmmm.... did you figure it out?  Can you show me a side photo?

Comment: I did it! There is something like a little groove at the side - at the connection between black and white parts - wherein I slotted a screwdriver, twisted it, and the light cover pulled off. Eureka!

Comment: @Lukman, please provide and accept your findings as an answer so that the question can be resolved. [Take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) if I'm not making sense.